# Angular 2 Component @Input not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am stuck on trying to pass a property value into my component. From what I've read everything looks correct. But it is still not working. My test value gets output to the screen and the console as null. :(

**This is my test component:**

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'TestCmp',
    template: `Test Value : {{test}}`
})

export class TestCmp {

    @Input() test: string;

    constructor()
    {
        console.log('This if the value for user-id: ' + this.test);
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling the component from the parent page.

```
<TestCmp [test]='Blue32'></TestCmp>
```

When the page render's the test value is empty. I only see 'Test Value :'.

Instead of 'Test Value : Blue32'.

Comment: Don't use CamelCase names in templates. HTML is case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks alex! I guess I have to change that habbit. ;0)

Comment: Even better: <testCmp test="Blue32"></testCmp>
you can remove the square brackets around the input name to put in a string value versus a component property.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You have four things that I can note :

- You are passing an input in the root component, which will not work.
- As @alexpods mentioned, you are using CamelCase. You should not.
- You are passing an expression instead of an string through `[test]`. That means that angular2 is looking for a variable named `Blue32` instead of passing a raw string.
- You are using the constructor. That will not work, it must be after the <s>view has been initialized</s> data-bound properties have been initialized (see docs for [OnInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html)).

So with a few fixes it should work

*Example updated to beta 1*

```js
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
  selector : 'childcmp',
  template: `Test Value : {{test}}`
})
class ChildCmp {
    @Input() test: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('This if the value for user-id: ' + this.test);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'testcmp',
    template : `<childcmp [test]="'Blue32'"></childcmp>`
    directives : [ChildCmp]
})
export class TestCmp {}

bootstrap(TestCmp);
```

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CO7kmS?p=preview) as an example.

## Update

I see that people still reach this answer, so I've updated the plnkr to beta 1 and I corrected one point on the explanation : You can access inputs in ngAfterViewInit, but you can access them earlier in the lifecycle within ngOnInit.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the help!... Those are some very good points. "AfterViewInit" will really come in handy. :)

Comment: That plunkr seems broken, I see only "Test Value :" on latest Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: @aikeru thanks for letting me know. That's really weird, the plnkr barely looked like the code in the answer. Anyway, I fixed it :)

Comment: If the input variable is assigned in a async call, it is still "undefined" when it runs ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit. In this case, where is the best place to perform actions when the input variable is initialized?

Comment: Hi @EricMartinez, would you mind looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601876/input-binding-doesnt-work-when-i-put-it-under-a-router-component). I am very grateful if you help :)

Comment: It is PascalCase, not camelCase.

Comment: @EricMartinez Great answer! Could you please reference docs where I can read more about point 1. I remember there being mention of similar limitations with root scope in Angular1 but this is new to me for Angular2.

Comment: For anyone else the part of this solution that fixed this for me was using `<childcmp [test]="'Blue32'">` instead of `<childcmp [test]="Blue32">` (the double quoted thing)

Comment: The two types of quotes is something where one can easily get tripped up.  this code example was helpful.

Comment: How can I pass service object type of data from one component to other component by using @Input or any other method

Comment: If you are passing a string, there is no need to use brackets, just say test="Blue32". Use brackets when you want to use variable name that exist in the .ts file

Answer (score 18):

It's that easy as surrounding the string with double quotes, like this:

```
<TestCmp [test]="'Blue32'"></TestCmp>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use brackets [] the Angular uses property binding and expects to receive an **expression** inside the quotes and it looks for a property called 'Blue32' from your component class or a variable inside the template.

If you want to pass string as a value to the child component you can pass it like so:

```
<child-component childProperty='passing string'></child-component>
```

or if you for some reason want to have the brackets:

```
<child-component [childProperty]="'note double quotes'"></child-component>
```

And then take it in to child.component.ts like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({})
export class ChildComponent {

    @Input()
    childProperty: string;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

This angular class could make the trick for static attributes:
**ElementRef**
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html

```
import {ElementRef} from 'angular2/core'

constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('api')
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. You are the savior Charles!

Comment: thanks gautam1168. I fixed the link expiration issue

Answer (score 3):

> Sharing what worked for me:

**Adding an input to the Angular 4 app**

Assuming that we have 2 components:

- `parent-component`
- `child-component`

We wanted to pass some value from `parent-component` to `child-component` i.e. an `@Input` from `parent-component.html` to `child-component.ts`. Below is an example which explains the implementation:

`parent-component.html` looks like this:

`<child-component [someInputValue]="someInputValue"></child-component>`

`parent-component.ts` looks like this:

```
  
  class ParentComponent {

  someInputValue = 'Some Input Value';

}
```

`child-component.html` looks like this:

`<p>Some Input Value {{someInputValue}}</p>`

`child-component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() someInputValue: String = "Some default value";

  @Input()
  set setSomeInputValue(val) {
    this.someInputValue += " modified";
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log('someInputValue in constructor ************** ', this.someInputValue); //someInputValue in constructor ************** undefined
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('someInputValue  in ngOnInit ************** ', this.someInputValue); //someInputValue  in ngOnInit ************** Some Input Value
  }
}
```

Notice that the value of the `@Input` value is available inside `ngOnInit()` and not inside `constructor()`.

**Objects reference behaviour in Angular 2 / 4**

In Javascript, objects are stored as [references](http:////jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/dftagmaf/).

This exact behaviour can be re-produced with the help of Angular 2 / 4. Below is an example which explains the implementation:

`parent-component.ts` looks like this:

```
  
  class ParentComponent {

  someInputValue = {input: 'Some Input Value'};

}
```

`parent-component.html` looks like this:

```
  
{{someInputValue.input}}
```

`child-component.html` looks like this:

```
Some Input Value {{someInputValue}}
change input
```

`child-component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() someInputValue = {input:"Some default value"};

  @Input()
  set setSomeInputValue(val) {
    this.someInputValue.input += " set from setter";
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log('someInputValue in constructor ************** ', this.someInputValue); //someInputValue in constructor ************** undefined
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('someInputValue  in ngOnInit ************** ', this.someInputValue); //someInputValue  in ngOnInit ************** Some Input Value
  }

  changeInput(){
    this.someInputValue.input += " changed";
  }
}
```

The function `changeInput()` will change the value of `someInputValue` inside both `ChildComponent` & `ParentComponent` because of their reference. Since, `someInputValue` is referenced from `ParentComponent`'s `someInputValue` **object** - the change in `ChildComponent`'s `someInputValue` **object** changes the value of `ParentComponent`'s `someInputValue` **object**. *THIS IS NOT CORRECT*. The references shall never be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem here might have to do with the page's life cycle. Because inside the constructor the value of this.test is null. But if I add a button to the template linked to a function that pushes the value to the console (same as I am doing in the constructor) this.test will actually have a value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look like a *hammer*, but you can put the input wrapped on an object like this:

```
<TestCmp [test]='{color: 'Blue32'}'></TestCmp>
```

and change your class

```
class ChildCmp {
    @Input() test: any;
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('This if the value for user-id: ' + this.test);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to import input like this at top of child component

```
import { Directive, Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are making use of @Input for the angular interaction.It is always preferred approach to pass the data from parent to child in JSON object apparently it doesn't not restrict by @Angular Team to use local variable or static variable.

In context to access the value on child component make use **ngOnInit(){} angular life hook cycle** regardless of constructor.

That will help you out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue there was actually just a compile error that I had to fix first (circular dependency needed resolved).