# @Input binding doesn't work when I put it under a router component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

**Updated**

**`Answer`**

I've just found out what happened. I have to load the script `pollyfills` after `systemjs`. Well, this is an known issue of the router:

**`Concat/Load Order`**

```
'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js'
```

---

**Problem**

I am trying to use my own component library in my app.
After I put the component under a page inside a `router` component, the component's `title` decorated with `@Input` doesn't show up:

I need it renders the `title` properties inside the page.

PS:

- I see this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326376/angular-2-component-input-not-working) but it doesn't fit in my case.
- @Input: [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html)

**Dependencies**

```
{
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
}
```

**Component**

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
            OK MAN PLZ WORK
            {{title}}
    `
})
export class Test {
    @Input() title: string;
}
```

**Container**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {Test} from './test'

@Component({
    selector: 'container',
    directives: [Test],
    template: `
    <test title="test"></test>
    `
})
export class Container {

}
```

**Boot**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';

import {Container} from './container;

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', component: Container, name: 'Container'}
])
class AppComponent {}
bootstrap(AppComponent, ROUTER_PROVIDERS);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, title is an attribute:

```
<test title="test"></test>
```

You should use [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding):

```
<test [title]="test"></test>
```

Comment: Without `[..]` or `{{...}}` Angular ignores the attribute and it's a simple static DOM attribute handled by the browser only.

Comment: well you are wrong, that's one way of data binding only.
let take a look at [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html).

Comment: @PeterTang your question doesn't tell what the expected behavior is so all we can do is guessing.

Comment: Oh, I will edit it more clearly, thank @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: @PeterTang Try if it's working with this suggestion, so we can rule out other causes. If it works, we can talk about alternative syntax' if you need it (;

Comment: `title="test"` is a shorthand syntax for `[title]=" 'test' "` if `title` is an input property.  I don't particularly like this shortcut, because it really looks like we are assigning an HTML attribute (especially if the input property name is a common HTML attribute name like `title`!).  But it does property binding. The only place I've seen this shorthand syntax mentioned is in a Savkin blog post: http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax  See the "Passing Constants" section.

Comment: Okay, I see that it is mentioned in passing in the [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding) dev guide: "If we forget the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and initializes the target property with that string. It does not evaluate the string!"  (I found it by searching for the word `constant`.)

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the answer! Hope it will help anyone :). I spent all night to figure out what happen :'(

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I received the test value in the `title` input. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/dZSMbVnvoNRXSbiNFbQX?p=preview.

What is the expected behavior, you want that `{{title}}` displays `"test"`?

Comment: yes, that's what i want. The page shows `loading...`, the console reports XHR error :(

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)
angular2-polyfills.js:138 Error: XHR error (404 OK) loading https://run.plnkr.co/L3tGUqDykU61O2Cf/app/main.ts(…)

Comment: I think that it's because of your base ref ;-)

Comment: You should update `<base href="/something/"></base>` right after your `<head>`. The id isn't the right one if you forked my plunkr...

Comment: well, I used the same `base` tag, and I didn't fork it. Is it the same with the url part plnkr.com/edit/`id` ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I get the id in the Source tab in the develop tools. Something under `run.plunkr.co`. Get the id from there and use it into in the base tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104416/discussion-between-peter-tang-and-thierry-templier).