# Setting a static literal values in an angular2 component

Tags: php, static, angular

In angular 2, it possible to set values within the html view of a component like this? It's already rendered in PHP:

```
//html page:
<dropdown [(options)]="['Available', 'Busy', 'Away', 'Offline']"></dropdown>
```

I have never seen this done anywhere online, so I assume it can't be done. But is there a workaround? For example if I had 100 `dropdown` components on the page with their own `options` model, I'd potentially have to make 100 requests to the server if doing it the angular way.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 //html page:
 <dropdown [options]="['Available', 'Busy', 'Away', 'Offline']"></dropdown>
```

---

- This template is perfectly OK for angular, as long as you use it for one-way binding using `[prop]="expression"` or `prop="{{expression}}"`,

  [**WORKING PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5KhDF00hpyEuxk6B3E21?p=preview)

---

- because the moment you try to do two-way binding `[(prop)]="expression"` over an `Array Value` it will fail, that's because `expression` must be a `component property` to do `two-way` binding.

  It will throw a `Teplate parse error`, to be precise.

  [**BROKEN PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0pJZTNydLXh2pFHrvP3J?p=preview)

Comment: Wonderfully explained answer. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: here is a similar issue for setting values on root elements which is worth referencing: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858. Basically this question is going against best practice.

Comment: Getting the attributes from html: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326376/angular-2-component-input-not-working/33329647#33329647