# input binding not working in Angular/IntelliJ

Tags: angular

Why is the input binding not working? I have taken the framework code created by IntelliJ and have replaced the default `app` component with my component `my-para`. Following is the code snippet.

index.html

```
<body>
  <my-para [paratext]="say something"></my-para>
</body>
```

paragraph.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-para',
  inputs: ['paratext'],
  template:`
    <p>Hello {{this.paratext}}</p>
  `
})

export class MyParaComponent {
   @Input() paratext: string;   
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MyParaComponent} from './paragraph.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyParaComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [MyParaComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I see only "hello" but not "hello say something"

Comment: `<my-para [paratext]=" 'say something' "></my-para>`. That "say something" part needs to be a string. But there are a lot of redundant lines in your code. Please follow the official documentation: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: sorry, didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use square brackets, it tries to bind an object.
So `<my-para [paratext]="say something"></my-para>` code looks for "say something" attribute.

Just pass your string without brackets.

`<my-para paratext="say something"></my-para>`

Also another node,

In your index.html there should be an app component only. 
Use it inside your app.component.html
`<my-para paratext="say something"></my-para>`

Inside your MyParaComponent component, just use @Input() decorator not inputs attribute of Component. You are defining your inputs twice.

Comment: didn't understand what you mean by defining the input twice? Wouldn't there be a name clash if the variable was getting defined twice?

Answer (score 0):

Got help from following SO answer (some points were mentioned by you guys as well)

[Angular 2 Component @Input not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326376/angular-2-component-input-not-working)

It seems I cannot pass input in root component. Explanation is here - [Angular 2 input parameters on root directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640178/angular-2-input-parameters-on-root-directive)

I created AppComponent. Then in AppComponent's template, I used MyParaComponent

index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<my-para [paratext]="'say something'"></my-para>`
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.module.ts - had to add both AppComponent and MyParaComponent in declarations

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyParaComponent
  ],
```