# Passing data from grand-parent component to child component with input binding

Tags: angular, components, inputbinding

My goal is to pass the **locations** array from the **results.component** (grand-parent) to **destination-selector.component** (parent) through the **bid-filter.component** (child).

**results.ts (grand-parent)**

```
this.subscriptions.add(
      this.customerService.getAllDestinations().subscribe(loc => {
        this.locations = loc.payload;
        console.log("from results",this.locations);
      })
    );
```

The log here is defined and shows the locations array

**results.html (grand-parent)**

```
<app-bid-filter [locations]="locations" [selectedValues]="selectedValues"
          (search)="toggleFilters();search($event)"></app-bid-filter>
```

**bid-filter.ts (parent)**

```
@Input() locations;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.isHome = this.router.url === '/home';
      console.log(this.locations);
     }
```

the log here is undefined

**bid-filter.html(parent)**

```
app-destination-selector (selectedDestination)="selectedLocation($event)" [destinations]="locations"
  [defaultDestinationId]="selectedValues?.destination"></app-destination-selector>
```

**destination-selector.ts (child)**

```
 @Input() destinations;
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.destinations);
  }
```

shows undefined as well

Am I missing something pretty obvious over here? I checked a couple of solutions which were not applicable to my issue [Angular 2 Component @Input not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326376/angular-2-component-input-not-working)

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use location as Observable i.e `this.locations$ = this.customerService.getAllDestinations().pipe(tap(loc) => loc.payload)` and in template `[locations]="locations$ | async"`

Answer (score 0):

Passing data through multiple components may get confusing and more prone to getting data as undefined. A better approach would be to use a `Service`. You can follow below steps

Create the service

```
export class MyService() {
  locasionsSubject$ = BehaviourSubject<any[]>([]);
  locasions$ = this.locasionsSubject$.asObservable();
}
```

The above service is then injected to the component that updates the `locations` and the component that receives the `locations`
**

**results.ts (grand-parent)**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
this.subscriptions.add(
  this.customerService.getAllDestinations().subscribe(loc => {
     this.locations = loc.payload;
     this.myService.locasionsSubject$.next(this.locations)
     console.log("from results",this.locations);
  })
 );
```

**bid-filter.ts (parent)**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.locasions$.subscribe({
    next: (locations) => this.locations = locations
  })
  this.isHome = this.router.url === '/home';
  console.log(this.locations);
}
```